# Calling functions inside of const references

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

Hi I am trying to have a getter in my class that returns a "read-only" reference to a vector of objects. Each of those objects its own variables and functions, that I need to call. The way that I am trying to set this up is to have the getter in the main class return a const reference. However, I don't seem to be able to access the values of the objects held in the vector. Is there a better way to do this? Here is a smallest reproducible example. Thank you.

```
#include <vector>
class Obj
{
private:
    int val;
public:
    Obj() { val = 10; }
    inline int getVal() { return val; }
};

class Foo
{
private:
    std::vector<Obj> obsVec;
public:
    Foo()
    {
        Obj a;
        Obj b;
        obsVec.push_back(a);
        obsVec.push_back(b);
    }
    const std::vector<Obj>& getConstRef() const { return obsVec; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.getConstRef()[0].getVal(); // Here is where I get the error
    return 0;
}
```

The error that I get is:

> Error (active)    E1086   the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "Obj::getVal"

Comment: G++ gives a better message  whining about missing `const`: *error: passing 'const value_type' {aka 'const Obj'} as 'this' argument discards qualifiers*

Comment: `inline int getVal() { return val; }` should be `int getVal() const { return val; }` by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `getVal()` as const:

```
inline int getVal() const { return val; }
```

instead of:

```
inline int getVal() { return val; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`foo.getConstRef()[0]` returns `const A &`, but `getVal` is not marked `const`.

Also note that `inline` is useless here, since functions defined (rather than declared) in class body are implicitly `inline`.